# Magento 2: I want to show customer ui component grid in my custom module

Tags: customer, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I want to show customer **ui_component** grid in my custom module and set collection according to customer attribute value.

I have **test** yes/no customer attribute. I want to show only those particular customer in my custom grid whom test value is set to **yes**

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given in the reference link; modify the file(s), as per your requirements.

[Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component)