# Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, product-grid

I have added product grid in Magento 2 admin form using this link:
[product grid](http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/05/magento-2-add-products-grid-to-custom-admin-module.html).
But now I am creating admin form using ui component and I am not able to change product grid using ui component. Please help me.

> view/adminhtml/layout/productlabel_productlabel_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="productlabel_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/productlabel_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="assign_products">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products in Category</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="assign_products_container" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\AssignProducts</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

Please Help!

Comment: show your code what you have tried and where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check this.

**Step 1:
Add the following code in your ui form**

```
 <fieldset name="assign_products">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign Products</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="assign_products_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit\AssignProducts</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

**Step 2: Create  `AssignProducts.php` in `Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit`**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit;

    class AssignProducts extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
    {
        /**
         * Block template
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $_template = 'products/assign_products.phtml';

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
         */
        protected $blockGrid;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
         */
        protected $registry;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
         */
        protected $jsonEncoder;


        protected $_productCollectionFactory;

        /**
         * AssignProducts constructor.
         *
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
            \Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory, //your custom collection
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->registry = $registry;
            $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
            $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve instance of grid block
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         */
        public function getBlockGrid()
        {

            if (null === $this->blockGrid) {
                $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit\Tab\Product',
                    'category.product.grid'
                );
            }
            return $this->blockGrid;
        }

        /**
         * Return HTML of grid block
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getGridHtml()
        {

            return $this->getBlockGrid()->toHtml();
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getProductsJson()
        {

            $vProducts = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',  $this->getItem()->getCustomerId()) 
                                    ->addFieldToSelect('product_id');   
            $products = array();
            foreach($vProducts as $pdct){      
                $products[$pdct->getProductId()]  = '';
            }       

            if (!empty($products)) {
                return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($products);
            }
            return '{}';
        }

        public function getItem()
        {
            return $this->registry->registry('my_item');
        }
    }
```

**Step3:Create Product.php in `Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit\Tab\`**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    protected $logger;
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;


    protected $_productCollectionFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('catalog_category_products');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getItem()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('my_item');
    }

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {

        // Set custom filter for in category flag
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_category') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
            } elseif (!empty($productIds)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if ($this->getItem()->getId()) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_category' => 1]);
        }       
        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'price'
        )->joinField(
            'position',
            'catalog_category_product',
            'position',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'category_id=' . (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
            'left'
        );
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        if ($storeId > 0) {
            $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
        }


        $this->setCollection($collection);

        if ($this->getItem()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        } 

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if (!$this->getItem()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'in_category',
                [
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'in_category',
                    'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                    'index' => 'entity_id',
                    'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                    'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ),
                'index' => 'price'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => !$this->getItem()->getProductsReadonly()
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('module/products/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_products');
        if ($products === null) {   
            $vProducts = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',  $this->getItem()->getCustomerId()) 
                                ->addFieldToSelect('product_id');   
            $products = array();
            foreach($vProducts as $pdct){      
                $products[]  = $pdct->getProductId();
            }       
        }
        return $products;
    }
}
```

**Step4:Create `assign_products.phtml` in `Namespace\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\products\`**

```
<?php
$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();
?>
<?php  echo $block->getGridHtml(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="category_products" id="in_category_products" data-form-part="your_form" value="" />
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Namespace_Module/products/assign-products": {
                "selectedProducts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductsJson(); ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}'; ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- @todo remove when "UI components" will support such initialization -->
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

**Step 4: Copy `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/category/assign-products.js`  to `Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/products/`**

**Step 5: Create `Grid.php` `Namespace/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Products`**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Products;

class Grid extends \Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Products\Product
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory
     */
    protected $resultRawFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Grid Action
     * Display list of products related to current category
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $item = $this->_initItem(true);
        if (!$item) {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('module/item/new', ['_current' => true, 'id' => null]);
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw $resultRaw */
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        return $resultRaw->setContents(
            $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
                'Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit\Tab\Product',
                'category.product.grid'
            )->toHtml()
        );
    }

     protected function _initItem($getRootInstead = false)
    {
        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
        $myModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\Module\Model\Item');

        if ($id) {
            $myModel->load($id);            
        }

        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('item', $myModel);
        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('my_item', $myModel);
        $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config');
        return $storeModel;
    }   


}
```

**Step 6: Create `Product.php Namespace/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Products`**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Products;


abstract class Product extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Namespace_Module::item_list';


}
```

Comment: I following above spates but i getting one error `Call to a member function getProductsReadonly() on null in Product.php` can you help me ?

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: Same issue here. regards

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: @JancyAbraham I am getting same error 
Call to a member function getProductsReadonly() on null in Product.php

Comment: @JancyAbraham can you please share your code in GitHub or another place.

Comment: @JancyAbraham How can I save the product ids so when I open the page it will show the selected product ids?

Comment: How to display category name in this grid?

Comment: where is assign-products.js file?

Comment: @AveshNaik  Copy vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/category/assign-products.js to Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/products/

Comment: Call to a member function getProductsReadonly() on null 

Any solution to this?

Comment: This is just a copy/paste of products grid show in Adminhtml > Catalog > Categories > Products in categories. That's why you are getting the error `Call to a member function getProductsReadonly() on null`. The method `getProductsReadonly` is a part of category, check: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product.php` line 160 (Aprox.).

Comment: Once I edit then save again the records at that time assigned products are not saving into the database, does anyone know why?

Comment: @JancyAbraham
what will be \Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory, //your custom collection ?
can you please give example ?

Comment: @JancyAbraham, how to a button link in the product grid , on clicking is there any way to load the pop up like adding Related or upsell products in product form?

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are getting this **getProductsReadonly() on null** type of error try to remove getCategory() check and also remove getId() check than products grid will be shown
2. Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory, //your custom collection ? can you please give example

If you don't know what is this 2nd number question than it is simple copy Product/Collection.php class from Module-cataloge and create in your custom module in same path rename only namespace with your module name.

Kindly kudos me if you done or if you have any queries regarding this comment here