# Magento 2 : Not getting the product grid in a custom form using UI component

Tags: magento2, adminform, uicomponent, product-grid

I want to show product grid in admin form using UI component, for that, I have added the following code in **product_form.xml**

```
  <fieldset name="assign_products">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="assign_products_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\AssignProducts</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

And in **AssignProducts.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module;

class AssignProducts extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'catalog/category/edit/assign_products.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
     */
    protected $blockGrid;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonEncoder;

    /**
     * AssignProducts constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve instance of grid block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getBlockGrid()
    {

        if (null === $this->blockGrid) {
            $this->blockGrid = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Tab\Product',
                'category.product.grid'
            );
        }
        return $this->blockGrid;
    }

    /**
     * Return HTML of grid block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {

        return $this->getBlockGrid()->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductsJson()
    {
        $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
        if (!empty($products)) {
            return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($products);
        }
        return '{}';
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current category instance
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('faqs');
    }
}
```

In **Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Tab\Product.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Tab;

use Company\Module\Model\ModuleFactory;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Contact factory
     *
     * @var ContactFactory
     */
    protected $moduleFactory;

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    protected $_objectManager = null;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param ModuleFactory $attachmentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        ModuleFactory $moduleFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->moduleFactory = $moduleFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * _construct
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {

        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('productsGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('prdt_id')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_product' => 1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * add Column Filter To Collection
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        // Set custom filter for in category flag
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_product') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();

            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
            } elseif (!empty($productIds)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * prepare collection
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        /* @var $model \Webspeaks\ProductsGrid\Model\Slide */
        $model = $this->_objectManager->get('\Company\Module\Model\Module');

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_product',
            [
                'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_product',
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Product ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'class' => 'xxx',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('Sku'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'class' => 'xxx',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'index' => 'price',
                'width' => '50px',
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/productsgrid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @param  object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return '';
    }

    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $product = $this->getPrdt();
        return $product->getProducts($product);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve selected products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $product = $this->getPrdt();
        $selected = $product->getProducts($product);

        if (!is_array($selected)) {
            $selected = [];
        }
        return $selected;
    }
    protected function getPrdt()
    {
        $prdtId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('prdt_id');
        $product   = $this->moduleFactory->create();
        if ($prdtId) {
            $product->load($prdtId);
        }
        return $product;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component

Comment: can you show "screen page" or javascript console error ?