# Magento 2 : How to add a product grid (assign product) in custom module using UI Component?

Tags: magento2, product, module, grid

I want to add product grid (assign product) in my custom module using UI Component.

I follow this ANSWER:

[Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component)

and I get the error like:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::getProductsReadonly()
>   in
>   /home/public_html/magento2110/app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Products/Edit/Tab/Product.php
>   on line 133

**If you already fixed above error so please help me to solve it or
If you have another way to fix it so please let me know.**

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you are calling a wrong method with product object in

> Step3: Create Product.php in
>   Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit\Tab\

Just comment following code block in above example,

```
/*if ($this->getItem()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        } */
```