# Insert Product Grid in custom module form uicomponent

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, product-grid

I am developing a custom module for Magento 2.2.x which should allow users to associate products to custom entity.

What I would like to do is to show a product grid in the edit form of the custom entity where users can search and select which products associate the custom entity.

I already created the form with uicomponent, this is the layout XML (`customentity_entity_edit.xml`)

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="customentity_entity_look.store.switcher" template="Magento_Backend::store/switcher.phtml" >
                <action method="setUseConfirm">
                    <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="customentity_entity_look_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is the xml of the form (`customentity_entity_look_form.xml`)

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    ...
    <fieldset name="main_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Main Information</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="store_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                    <!--<item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>-->
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">main_fieldset</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">main_fieldset</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">main_fieldset</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[STORE]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="assign_products">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign Products</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="assign_products_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">\Vendor\Module\Block\To\Show\Product\Grid</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I don't know how to implement the block which should render the product grid (`\Vendor\Module\Block\To\Show\Product\Grid`)

I tried to follow this [Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component) but it throws several errors at runtime and it uses deprecated core classes.

Is there a standard way to show this control in a form of a custom module?

Answer (score 2):

You can make innergrid with also ui-component using innserlisting

```
 <insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">make_custom_listing</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>
```

Comment: thank you for pointing me in a direction. however I am not able to fetch the product for the listing. Is there any good example/tutorial I can follow?

Comment: just replace innerlisting code with  <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">\Vendor\Module\Block\To\Show\Product\Grid</argument>
            </htmlContent> code

Comment: And make another grid for product listing

Comment: ok, but how do I fetch the products?

Comment: In that product listing you can define datasource and using that datasource you use model,resourcemodel and grid-collection 
Here is the example of how to create admin grid https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html