# Add product grid in custom module using ui component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, list-view

I have followed this solution [Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component) but i am getting this

[image]

What i am doing wrong can any one help me on this.
Edit Controller

```
class Edit extends Action
{

protected $resultRawFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
 */
protected $layoutFactory;

public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_outfitFactory = $celebrityFactory;
    $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
    $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
}

/**
 * Execute action based on request and return result
 *
 * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
 */
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        return $resultRaw->setContents(
            $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
                'Allure\Celebrities\Block\Adminhtml\Products\Edit\Tab\Product',
                'category.product.grid'
            )->toHtml()
        );  

    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($exception->getMessage());
    }
    $this->_redirect("*/celebrities/index");
    return;
}

protected function _initItem($getRootInstead = false)
{
    $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
    $myModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Allure\Celebrities\Model\Celebrity');

    if ($id) {
        $myModel->load($id);
    }

    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('item', $myModel);
    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('my_item', $myModel);
    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config');
    return $myModel;
}


}
```

Comment: I think the css file of page is not coming. Can you check the console and also try running content deploy, cache and indexing commands

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it seems to be working
http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/05/magento-2-add-products-grid-to-custom-admin-module.html

Comment: That is an alternate solution. I want it using UI component.

Comment: https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-use-ui-components-in-magento-2/