# magento2 how to add product grid in ui form using ui component

Tags: magento2, product, uicomponent, ui-form, product-grid

[Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component/152092#152092)

this refreance is not work me it is display look like layout grid

Comment: this is not work for me

Comment: If that is the case, you should have added detail into your question otherwise it is pretty confusing for others. I retracted my close vote, add detail in your question

Comment: https://prnt.sc/oe32es i want to add assing product tab click display product grid using ui component

Answer (score 0):

The following reference adds the productgrid in uiform
https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-product-grid-in-ui-form-using-uicomponent/