# How to add a custom product collection like cross-sell, up-sell, related products in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, product-list

I'm currently working on a shopping project for a water management company using Magento 2.3. The client asking a new product collection named consumable products for each product, like related, up-sell, cross-sell. I need to develop for adding consumable products of each product in the backend like related, up-sell and cross-sell. Please guide me to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can assign **Related Products**, **Up-Sells**, and **Cross-Sells** Products from Admin Panel. Open Particular product and assigned in Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells section. You can see the assigned Related(named Related Products) and Up-Sells Product(named We found other products you might like!) on Product Page and Cross-Sells Product(named More Choices:) on Cart Page.

[image]

You can also override collections files in the theme directory.

Comment: Thank you bro. But I need 4th one. Client want Consumable along with Up-sell, Cross sell, Related products. He asking 4 product collections. Shall I can add 4 scrollers in all product page using backend bro?

Comment: Need another section in which client can add their custom product and displayed on Product Page?

Comment: yes. He need related, cross-sell, up-sell, consumable in all product pages

Comment: You can review here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component