# Adding a Product Grid in Dynamic Rows

Tags: magento2, product-grid, modal-popup

I want to add a product grid in Dynamic Rows using Modal what I have done so far is

[image: Grid]

I have added this button using [Adding Modal in Ui Component](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-modal.html)

add added a  [Product Grid in Modal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152092/77582)

But I am not getting selected products on form submitting

I think there is an issue with `data-form-part` when I submit product I get selected id with form

please let me know hat will be `data-form-part` if the input of htmlContent in dynamic Rows

Comment: do u have answer this??

Comment: yess.. but  i am sill working on it

Comment: do you used separate table to save these items

Comment: you have create a sperate table but I just saved data as soon in single column