# Magento 2 how to add product grid in custom module using ui component

Tags: magento2, product, grid, product-grid

Magento 2  : I have add product grid from the below refferance Once I edit then save again the records at that time assigned products are not saving into the database, does anyone know why?

**[Magento 2 : How to add a product grid in custom module using ui component?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149833/magento-2-how-to-add-a-product-grid-in-custom-module-using-ui-component)**

Comment: Use this link : https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-how-to-add-product-grid-in-ui-form-using-uicomponent/

Comment: it's work for me thanks for the refferance.

Comment: Can I add as answer? So, you can mark as accept and it will helpful for others.

Comment: yes please add answer